# Can someone explain me this C structure syntax?

Tags: c, struct

I found on [this official gnu gcc website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) that they initialize structures like that:

```
struct f1 {
  int x; int y[];
} f1 = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } };

struct f2 {
  struct f1 f1; int data[3];
} f2 = { { 1 }, { 2, 3, 4 } };
```

At first I thought it was a default initialization for the struct, but I tested it and it doesn't auto-initialize the struct when declared, so what's the point of using this (I compiled my program with gcc of course).

The code I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct a{
int x;
int y;
} a = {42, 42};

int main(void)
{
  struct a foo;

  printf("%d\n%d\n", foo.x, foo.y);
  return (0);
}
```

And it outputs random uninitialized data instead of

```
42
42
```

Comment: But you understand what does `struct f1 some_var_name = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } };` means?

Comment: Oh okay, it just initializes one member, my bad

Comment: **Did you read a recent C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)?** It has the answer. See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Your `y` field is a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: Using the same name `f1` for the struct tag and for an object of the type is legal but not exactly good style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion seems to stem from the fact that you do not understand the syntax.

```
struct f1 {
  int x; int y[];
} f1 = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } };
```

defines a **variable** named `f1` with it's members initialized.

In your example, you also have a variable `a` initialized in the global scope, but you also have the same variable `a` in `main` scope, which is left uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that so I auto-answered my question at the same time x)

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood, this is equivalent to `struct f1 f1 = { 1, {2, 3, 4}};`, the fact that they used the same name `f1` made me think that this was a new syntax.